# The document Class ''els-cas'' cannot not print subfigure

Tags: subfloats, subcaption, subfig, els-cas

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-sc}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{figure}%[!htb]
%\minipage{0.32\textwidth}

 \begin{subfigure}%[b]%{1\textwidth}
 \centering
%\fbox{
       \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{FE_CDF2.eps}
        \caption{FE grid }
        \label{fig:(a)}
    \end{subfigure}%

%\endminipage\hfill
%\minipage{0.32\textwidth}

 \begin{subfigure}%[b]%{1\textwidth}
 \centering
 %\fbox{
        \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Daytown_CDF2.eps}
        \caption{Daytown grid }
      \label{fig:(b)}
    \end{subfigure}
%\endminipage\hfill
%\minipage{0.32\textwidth}%
  \begin{subfigure}%[b]%{1\textwidth}
  \centering
  %\fbox{
        \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{EKPC_CDF2.eps}
        \caption{EKPC grid }
\label{fig:(c)}
    \end{subfigure}
%\endminipage
\caption{CDF of daily MAPE on FE, Daytown, and EKPC grids data of USA for our proposed FCRBM based model and existing models (AFC-ANN, Bi-level, MI-ANN). }
\label{fig_CDF_USA_Grid}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your example compilable by adding the **relevant**  packages.

Comment: What's the reason for `[b]` and `{1\textwidth}` being commented out on every occurence of `subfigure`?

Comment: Because when [b] and {1\textwidth} uncommented  then file is not executable

Comment: @leandriis the relevant packages are added

Comment: Your example is still not compilable. There still seems to be missing a package. Also, `subfigure` definitely needs a width, som commenting out the `{1\textwidth}` will result in an error message.

Comment: Could you please also add a description or a sketch of the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With appropriate widths of the `subfigures` and some `\hfill` commands:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,demo]{cas-sc} % Remove the demo option in your real document.
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}%
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}\centering
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{FE_CDF2.eps}
      \caption{FE grid }
      \label{fig:(a)}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Daytown_CDF2.eps}
    \caption{Daytown grid }
    \label{fig:(b)}
  \end{subfigure}
\hfill
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{EKPC_CDF2.eps}
    \caption{EKPC grid }
    \label{fig:(c)}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{CDF of daily MAPE on FE, Daytown, and EKPC grids data of USA for our proposed FCRBM based model and existing models (AFC-ANN, Bi-level, MI-ANN). }
  \label{fig_CDF_USA_Grid}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Side note: although not needed for the contents of the document, not including the  `natbib` package leads to the following error message: `! Undefined control sequence. \@begindocumenthook ...\@afterindentfalse \bibsep=0pt\gdef \bibfont {\fonts...`

Answer (score 1):

The `subfigure` package is obsolete; anyway, its syntax is completely different and requires the command `\subfigure` rather than `\begin{subfigure}`.

The `subfigure` environment is provided by the `subcaption` package.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-sc}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx,natbib}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[pos=!htbp]
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{FE grid}\label{fig:(a)}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{Daytown grid}\label{fig:(b)}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{EKPC grid}\label{fig:(c)}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{CDF of daily MAPE on FE, Daytown, and EKPC grids data of USA for our proposed FCRBM based model and existing models (AFC-ANN, Bi-level, MI-ANN).}
\label{fig_CDF_USA_Grid}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Note that the class requires a different syntax for the positioning specification of a figure.

Don't end captions with a space. Also avoid `scale` because you'll not be in control of the width; prefer `width`.

[image]